# Error 1009, it is impossible to access the property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following action script class and when I instantiate the class by calling the constructor in a mxml file I have get "error 1009 it is impossible to access the property or method of a null object reference". Why do I receive this error?

```
package com.esprit.immocr.DTO
{
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;   
   [Bindable]
   [RemoteClass(alias="com.esprit.immocr.DTO.TypePieceDto")]
   public class Typ 
   {
       public var code_type_piec:  String;
       public var Libelle_t_piec: String;
       //Association
       public var clientsdto: ArrayCollection;
       public function Typ(o:Object):void
       {
            this.code_type_piec = o.code_type_piec;
            this.Libelle_t_piec = o.Libelle_t_piec;
            this.clientsdto = o.clientsdto;
       }    
    }
}
```

and the following mxml file using this class

```
protected function tpvalider(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //ro.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, tpvalider);
    tp.code_type_piec=codetp.text;
    tp.Libelle_t_piec=libtp.text;
    ro.createTppiece(tp); // ro is a reference to remote object 
}
private  var tp: Typ = new Typ(obj);
```

Comment: Please use English...

Comment: charlesworth do you understand my text

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Why don't you launch your swf in debug mode to get the line where the error occurs?

Comment: I'm wondering if obj isn't defined or instantiated when var tp is being set up.  It's always dangerous to do initialization of variables that depend of other variables this way - order of instantiation can cause all sorts of problems!

Comment: obj is a new object. it is defined as private var obj: Object = new Object();

Comment: I am using eclipse europa, mysql, and apache server. The application is flex using spring, hibernate 4 .

Comment: The error occurs, when I use the variable// private  var tp: Typ = new Typ(obj);

Comment: var tp: Typ = new Typ(obj); is used in fuction tpvalider(event) and it causes error 1009

Comment: I have used the debugger and it stops before the function tpvalider(event)// It stops in the declaration of the variable tp: Typ = new Typ(obj); and obj is :: var obj: Object = new Object();

Comment: anyone knows whats wrong?